# How to count the divisors not exceeding $\log ^2N$ of a given number $N$ in asymptotics?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms

In this book [Pseudorandomness](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/%7Esalil/pseudorandomness/) written by Salil P. Vadhan, I've faced a barrier in Problem 2.4 on page 41.

It says that given the fact that the number of primes less than $T$ is $(1\pm O(1))\cdot T/\ln T$, where $O(1)$ tends to $0$ as $T\to \infty$. It asks to prove that for M sampled uniformly from $\{1,\cdots,\log^2 N\}$, we have
$$
\Pr[N\not\equiv 0 \bmod M]=\Omega(1/\log \log N).
$$

I've done some research, like [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial). But they seems don't help with solving the problem.

By intuition, I think the problem asks to bound the number of divisors of $N$ that not exceeding $\log ^2 N$. Let $D=\log ^2 N$, its easy to see that there are at most $1.01 D/\ln D$ primes not exceeding $D$ for large enough $N$. Let $d=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}<D$ being an divsior of $N$, then we have $E=\sum_{n=1}^n e_n\leq O(\log \log N)$ since $D=2^{\log D}=2^{O(\log \log N)}$. Then I bound the number of such divisors roughly with permutation
$$
C_{E+D/\ln D}^{D/ln D}
$$
Which means the number of grouping the $E$ in the exponentials of primes to $D/\ln D$ groups.
I tried to calculate this with Stirling's approximation. However, this seems not being helpful for solving the problem.

So could somebody give me the solution or some hint about the problem?